# OpenReadAsync on CloudBlob returns empty stream

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an azure function (EventGrid trigger) that fires when a new blob gets created in the blob storage (Data Lake Storage Gen2).
In this function I need to read the blob and deserialize it to an object (type known).

This is the method I use to get the CloudBlob:

```
public async Task<CloudBlob> GetCloudBlob(Uri uri)
{
   var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlob(uri, _storageCredentials);
   if (await cloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync())
       return cloudBlockBlob;
   return null;
}
```

With this code I read the cloud blob

```
using var stream = await cloudBlob.OpenReadAsync();
await _requestFileHandler.HandleFile(stream, name, prefix, cloudBlob.Uri);
```

In the method HandleFile I call the DeserializeAsync method:

```
var model = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RequestModel>(stream);
```

For some reason, the stream is **some times** empty (stream.Length is 0) resulting in this exception.

```
The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

The funny thing is that, if I retry the process of this blob again, then the stream gets populated as expected.

Am I missing any wait condition, or can it be that the blob is still not yet fully written to the storage?

Comment: Convert `await cloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync()` to `await cloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`, `await cloudBlob.OpenReadAsync()` to `await cloudBlob.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`, `await _requestFileHandler.HandleFile(stream, name, prefix, cloudBlob.Uri)` to `await _requestFileHandler.HandleFile(stream, name, prefix, cloudBlob.Uri).ConfigureAwait(false)` and `await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RequestModel>(stream)` to `await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RequestModel>(stream).ConfigureAwait(false)`. It should most probably work.

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT why shuold this most probably work?

Comment: You can read this article to deep dive - https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f

Comment: yes I know that it is recommended to use ConfigureAwait(false). but the question: how this helps me in this case now?

Comment: When the `await` keyword is applied, it suspends the calling method and yields control back to its caller until the awaited task is complete. We can avoid forcing continuations/callbacks back to the original context, and we do that by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` causes performance issues and unreliability. Since, you are not using it, the `stream` is sometimes in Caller context and sometimes in current context. The one in current context gives you correct results. You can visit https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/ for more information.

Comment: Pls let me know if this answers your question, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Does this solution work?

Answer (score 1):

**Serializing to the stream leaves the stream positioned at the end**, so when you go to deserialize it, there's nothing to deserialize.

You need to add a line like:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

after you serialize and before you deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting `await cloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync()` to `await cloudBlockBlob.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`, `await cloudBlob.OpenReadAsync()` to `await cloudBlob.OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`, `await _requestFileHandler.HandleFile(stream, name, prefix, cloudBlob.Uri)` to `await _requestFileHandler.HandleFile(stream, name, prefix, cloudBlob.Uri).ConfigureAwait(false)` and `await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RequestModel>(stream)` to `await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RequestModel>(stream).ConfigureAwait(false)`.

When the `await` keyword is applied, it suspends the calling method and yields control back to its caller until the awaited task is complete. We can avoid forcing continuations/callbacks back to the original context, and we do that by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` causes performance issues and unreliability. Since, you are not using it, the `stream` is sometimes in Caller context and sometimes in current context. The one in current context gives you correct results. You can visit devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a blob input binding for your *EventGridTrigger* function to get the blob stream, see the following code snippet:

```
public static async Task Run(JObject eventGridEvent, Stream body, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"{eventGridEvent}");    
    // ...
    var model = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RequestModel>(body);                  
    // ...
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

and the function.json file:

```
 {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "eventGridEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "body",
      "path": "{data.url}",
      "connection": "rk2019dlstg_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```